# Pandas: Make a new column by linearly interpolating between existing columns

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a DataFrame containing data about the temperature at various altitudes on a mountain, each sampled simultaneously once per day.  The altitude of each probe is fixed (i.e. they stay constant from day to day) and is known.  Each row represents a different timestamp, and I have a separate column to record the temperature observed by each probe.  I also have a column (`targ_alt`) that contains an "altitudes of interest" for each row.

My goal is to add a new column called `intreped_temp` which contains, for each row, the temperature that you would get for that row's `targ_alt` by linearly interpolating between the temperatures of the probes at their known altitudes.  What is the best way to do this?

Here is some setup code so we can look at the same context:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)

n = 10
probe_alts = {'base': 1000, 'mid': 2000, 'peak': 3500}
# let's make the temperatures decrease at higher altitudes...just for style
temp_readings = {k: np.random.randn(n) + 15 - v/300 for k, v in probe_alts.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(temp_readings)

targ_alt = 2000 + (500 * np.random.randn(n))
df['targ_alt'] = targ_alt
```

So `df` looks like this:

```
        base        mid      peak     targ_alt
0  13.624345  10.462108  2.899381  1654.169624
1  11.388244   6.939859  5.144724  1801.623237
2  11.471828   8.677583  4.901591  1656.413650
3  10.927031   8.615946  4.502494  1577.397179
4  12.865408  10.133769  4.900856  1664.376935
5   9.698461   7.900109  3.316272  1993.667701
6  13.744812   8.827572  3.877110  1441.344826
7  11.238793   8.122142  3.064231  2117.207849
8  12.319039   9.042214  3.732112  2829.901089
9  11.750630   9.582815  4.530355  2371.022080
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the example I gave above, I wanted to interp to a different x-coordinate within each row.  Fine.  If you don't...if you want to interp to the same x-coordinate within each row, there are incredible time savings to be had by using SciPy.  See example below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

np.random.seed(1)
n = 10e4

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randn(n), 
                   'b': 10 + np.random.randn(n), 
                   'c': 30 + np.random.randn(n)})

xs = [-10, 0, 10]
cvs = df.columns.values
```

Now consider 3 different ways to tack on a column which will interpolate between the given columns to an x-coordinate of 5:

```
%timeit df['n1'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.interp(5, xs, row[cvs]), axis=1)
%timeit df['n2'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.interp(5, xs, tuple([row[j] for j in cvs])), axis=1)
%timeit df['n3'] = interp1d(xs, df[cvs])(5)
```

Here are the results for n=1e2:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 13.2 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.24 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 488 µs per loop
```

And for n=1e4:

```
1 loops, best of 3: 1.33 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 109 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 798 µs per loop
```

And for n=1e6:

```
# first one is too slow to wait for
1 loops, best of 3: 10.9 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 58.3 ms per loop
```

One followup question: is there a *fast* way to modify this code so that it could handle x inputs outside the min-max range of the training data through linear extrapolation?

Answer (score 2):

Ok.  I'm actually a bit surprised this worked, but here's a starting point.  Can anyone suggest a method where I don't need to do the `zip`ping to condense all the inputs for `np.interp` down to one column before using `map`? (**See edits below.  This is exactly what `DataFrame.apply` does...**)  I.e. is there a Pandas function that acts like `map` does for Series, but takes in an entire row of a DataFrame as its input (but doesn't involve `groupby`)?

Here's the code, starting where the question left off:

```
df['rolled'] = zip(df['targ_alt'], zip(df['base'], df['mid'], df['peak']))
%timeit df['interped_temp'] = df['rolled'].map(lambda x: np.interp(x[0], probe_alts.values(), x[1]))
del df['rolled']
```

This returns as desired:

```
        base        mid      peak     targ_alt  interped_temp
0  13.624345  10.462108  2.899381  1654.169624      11.555706
1  11.388244   6.939859  5.144724  1801.623237       7.822315
2  11.471828   8.677583  4.901591  1656.413650       9.637647
3  10.927031   8.615946  4.502494  1577.397179       9.592617
4  12.865408  10.133769  4.900856  1664.376935      11.050570
5   9.698461   7.900109  3.316272  1993.667701       7.911496
6  13.744812   8.827572  3.877110  1441.344826      11.574613
7  11.238793   8.122142  3.064231  2117.207849       7.726924
8  12.319039   9.042214  3.732112  2829.901089       6.104308
9  11.750630   9.582815  4.530355  2371.022080       8.333099
```

For `n=10`, `%timeit` gives 182us/loop.  For `n=1e6`, `%timeit` gives 4.51s/loop.  Very curious to see other approaches.

---

@DSM makes a great comment that `probe_alts.values()` could return in any order.  Here's a some cleaner code in the spirit of what was above:

```
probes = ['base', 'mid', 'peak']
df['rolled'] = zip(df['targ_alt'], zip(*[df[p] for p in probes]))
df['interped_temp'] = df['rolled'].map(lambda x: np.interp(x[0], tuple(probe_alts[p] for p in probes), x[1]))
del df['rolled']
```

and here is a method that looks a bit cleaner to me that just uses `DataFrame.apply` which might just be smarter overall...

```
probes = ['base', 'mid', 'peak']
def cust_interp(row):
    return np.interp(row['targ_alt'], tuple(probe_alts[p] for p in probes), row[probes])
df['interped_temp'] = df.apply(cust_interp, axis=1)
```

Comment: Warning: `probe_alts.values()` could return in any order.

Comment: @DSM, your point about arbitrary order for `probe_alts.values()` is a great gotcha.  Just thinking a bit more clearly about the original problem, you can certainly use `DataFrame.apply` to good effect here.  Adding that up above.

Comment: In 0.13, their is a whole new section on interpolation, see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html#missing-data-interpolate

Comment: @Jeff, thanks for the pointer to the new features in 0.13.  It seems like they're designed for cases where the interpolation will be done with respect to x-values that derive from the row index.  Do you know if 0.13 will include the ability to do interpolation with respect to column indices?  Either way, I think my above constructions are a decent reference for more customized interpolation techniques.

Answer (score 0):

One method may be to transpose the DataFrame, insert a row of NaNs (missing values) between the rows to be interpolated, interpolate (which fills in the values), and then transpose back:

```
df.transpose()
df.loc['intreped_temp'] = np.nan

# row needs to reside in between data columns for interpolating to work
# may require further index manipulation 
df.sort_index() 

df.interpolate()
df.transpose()
```

This strategy was derived from the information in the pandas interpolation guide here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/missing_data.html#interpolation