# Interpolation of a variable for different elevations (automatically determine x1 and x2)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, interpolation

I have a dataframe with 3 temperature values columns, as follows:

```
T1 at 1000 m
T2 at 2000 m
T3 at 3000m
```

And I have a list with different elevations ranging from 1000 to 3000.
For each elevation I want to create the interpolated temperature.
The main issue is that I can't make my code automatically select the correct columns. For example if my target elevation is 1500 I want to interpolate between 1000 and 2000. I am aiming for simple linear interpolation. I tried the method that is suggested in [Pandas: Make a new column by linearly interpolating between existing columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822153/pandas-make-a-new-column-by-linearly-interpolating-between-existing-columns)
But I kept getting TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable

Can you help me solve this problem?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(7), freq='D')
data = np.random.randint(1, high=50, size=len(days))
Elevation= np.random.randint(1000, high=3000, size=len(days))

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': days, 'T1000':data,'T2000':data,'T3000':data} )
df = df.set_index('Time')
print(df)
```

Comment: What kind of interpolation are you doing?

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: Thank you so much and i'm sorry for the messy way i presented my question. I updated it now. I am  looking for  simple linear interpolation .

Answer (score 1):

You can simply interpolate for each row of the the DataFrame:

```
df['Alti'] = Elevation
df['Val'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.interp(x.Alti, [1000, 2000, 3000], x['T1000':'T3000']),
                     axis=1)
```